# Connecting MongoDB Atlas endpoint with VPN

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, mongodb-atlas, aws-vpn

I have setup a MongoDB Atlas. Also, I have configured a VPC peering from MongoDB Atlas to my AWS VPC. I have allowed VPC CIDR in the IP access list on MongoDB Atlas and it's working fine.

I also have a client VPN endpoint that I am using to connect AWS VPC via secure tunnel. I have also allowed my client VPN private IP range on MongoDB Atlas IP access list but I am **unable to connect to MongoDB Atlas endpoint**.

I tried to dig down further and performed these steps:

- **resolve hostname from SRV record:**

  nslookup -type=SRV _mongodb._tcp.clusterx.xxxxxxxxxx.mongodb.net
- **ping the hostname**

  ping clusterx-shard-xx-xx.xxxxxx.mongodb.net

When trying the ping from AWS VPC, it resolves to the private IP of that hostname but when I try to ping the hostname from local, it resolves to public IP of that hostname. **That was the reason I was unable to connect to MongoDB Atlas endpoint from my local.**

Is there any way to make MongoDB **connection work with private IP from my local**?

Comment: Good question, it seems you did RCA and identified the issue with DNS resolution of your VPN client. The fix could be as easy as changing the nameserver in your local network set up when you are connected via VPN. I would double check that IP resolution is the problem first. Get IP local IP from the ping command and try to ping by IP from your laptop. It should prove connectivity on network level and will confirm the issue is with the nameserver.

Comment: Actually, I am not sure if updating the aws vpc nameserver in local network helps. Do you know how can I get the aws vpc nameserver?

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/1/dig  https://linux.die.net/man/1/nslookup  or similar from within VPC where the name is properly resolved to local IP.

Comment: AWS uses split-horizon DNS.  If your client is not on the private segment the DNS will resolve to the public values.  If your client is on the private segment, the DNS will resolve to private values.  MongoDB Private Endpoints and VPC Peering on AWS leverage split-horizon DNS.  Like you state in your post, you are resolving the incorrect DNS horizon.  You would need to configure your VPN such that DNS is routed via VPN as well.  One way or another your client must resolve to the private IP addresses to connect to the AWS private endpoint.

Comment: You could create a connection string that is not a SRV type and refer to the private endpoint hosts assuming you can reach it from the client location on the public side of the VPN.  Since AWS uses a single endpoint for privatelink you would need to refer to the Atlas members by their relative port numbers too.  The NSLOOKUP command against the SRV DNS record will provide the port numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You're most probably missing the route to the Atlas instance within your VPN connection.

AWS is aware of the destination IP address (therefore, it is resolvable), but doesn't route your traffic to it (therefore, ping fails).

To resolve, you need to add the route to the Atlas instance - or add a default route that brings all the traffic through your VPN (which I do not recommend). [You can find out how to do it in more detail in AWS documentation.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-admin/cvpn-working-routes.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need bi-directional routing - your packets have to get from your machine to Atlas and packets from Atlas have to be able to get back to your machine. I am unsure if you can modify the routing table on the Atlas side to send the packets back.

Assuming it's not possible to modify the routing table on the Atlas side you will need to ensure that your outbound packets appear to come from an IP in the peered VPC instead of an external IP range.

The two easiest ways of doing that are:

- If your VPN is terminated inside the target VPC you may be able to enable SNAT (Source NAT) so that the VPN masks your IP (and sends all outbound packets using its own IP).
- If not, spin up an EC2 instance inside the target VPC and ssh to the instance and include a local port forward (-L) to forward a local port which you can then use to connect to Atlas.